# Null Pointer Exception - onPrepareDialog

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am making an app in which i am using dialog to accept, store and show data, and it works find for me, but whenever i do re launch my app, getting **NPE**

```
  @Override
    public void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
        switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_LOGIN:
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = (AlertDialog) dialog;
            .........
            .........
            // check for parent email  
             if(GetEventsActivity.parental.equals("no"))  // throwing error
            {   
                // hide
                parental_email.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else
            {
                 // show
                parental_email.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            ........
         }
    }
```

I am showing button in a list item, and whenever user do tap on that button i am showing Dialog.

```
        btnData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(DIALOG_LOGIN);
            }
        });
```

and **Log** says:

```
W/dalvikvm(26689): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a4d2a0)
E/AndroidRuntime(26689): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(26689): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(26689):    at app.mac.Camera.UploadActivity.onPrepareDialog(UploadActivity.java:469)
E/AndroidRuntime(26689):    at android.app.Activity.onPrepareDialog(Activity.java:3071)
E/AndroidRuntime(26689):    at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:3134)
E/AndroidRuntime(26689):    at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:3085)
E/AndroidRuntime(26689):    at app.mac.Camera.UploadActivity$ImageAdapter$2.onClick(UploadActivity.java:286)
E/AndroidRuntime(26689):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4223)
E/AndroidRuntime(26689):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17275)
E/AndroidRuntime(26689):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
E/AndroidRuntime(26689):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(26689):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(26689):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
E/AndroidRuntime(26689):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(26689):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(26689):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1036)
E/AndroidRuntime(26689):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:803)
E/AndroidRuntime(26689):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
I/Process(26689): Sending signal. PID: 26689 SIG: 9
```

Comment: what is your line 469 in `UploadActivity.java`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it does mean that

```
GetEventsActivity.parental
```

is `null`. On the other hand, I would like to suggest to compare always the constant string with  the one that can change

```
if ("no".equals(GetEventsActivity.parental))
```

this way you will avoid, at least the `NPE`, because the first test will be

```
if (! (GetEventsActivity.parental instanceof String))
 return false;
```

and `null instanceof String` is always `false`

Comment: whenever i am launching my app again, its showing parental_email edittext in dialog, but as per my logic it should be gone if "0"

Comment: You mean if (GetEventsActivity.parental == null) you want to set parental_email's visibility to gone?\

Comment: change if ("no".equals(GetEventsActivity.parental)) to if (GetEventsActivity.parental == null || "no".equals(GetEventsActivity.parental))

Comment: sorry for late reply was mid in small meeting, thanks a lot + 1000 this time, and will you brief this to me for future use